# Meteor update user profile

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have no idea what's going wrong in my app. I'm trying to update a user profile. If a user has already a profile, it should display the current values of the profile. I have a SimpleSchema attached to the user collection.

```
<template name="updateCustomerProfile">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit User</h1>
    {{#if isReady 'updateCustomerProfile'}}
      {{#autoForm collection="Users" doc=getUsers id="profileForm" type="update"}}
        <fieldset>
          {{> afQuickField name='username'}}
          {{> afObjectField name='profile'}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update User</button>
        <a class="btn btn-link" role="button" href="{{pathFor 'adminDocuments'}}">Back</a>
      {{/autoForm}}
    {{else}}
      Nothing
    {{/if}}
   </div>
</template>
```

I have a template helper:

```
Template.updateCustomerProfile.events({
getUsers: function () {
    //return Users.findOne();
    return Meteor.user();
  }
});
```

I have an Autoform hook

```
AutoForm.addHooks(['profileForm'], { 
    before: {
      insert: function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Insert Error:", error);
          AutoForm.debug();
        } else {
          console.log("Insert Result:", result);
          AutoForm.debug();
        }
      },
      update: function(error) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Update Error:", error);
          AutoForm.debug();
        } else {
          console.log("Updated!");
          console.log('AutoForm.debug()');
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Have the following route:

```
customerRoutes.route('/profile/edit', {
  name: "updateCustomerProfile",
  subscriptions: function (params, queryParams) {
    this.register('updateCustomerProfile', Meteor.subscribe('usersAllforCustomer',  Meteor.userId()));
  },
  action: function(params, queryParams) {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout_frontend', {
      top: 'menu',
      main: 'updateCustomerProfile',
      footer: 'footer'
    });
  }
});
```

and finally the following publication:

```
Meteor.publish('usersAllforCustomer', function (userId) {
    check(userId, String);
    var user = Users.findOne({_id: userId});
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'customer')) {
        return Users.find({_id: userId});
    }
});
```

And here is the collection:

```
Users = Meteor.users;

Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
        optional: true
    },
    organization : {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    }
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    emails: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        denyUpdate: true,
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isInsert) {
                return new Date();
            }
        }
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    roles: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

I'm sure the user object is passed in the publication. I can't update the profile: getting the following error (from Autoform debug):

```
Update Error: Object {$set: Object}
   $set: Object
        profile.firstName: "test_firstname"
        profile.gender: "Female"
        profile.lastName: "test_lastname"
        profile.organization: "test_organisation
        "username: "test_username"
```

How to go about updating a profile, staring blind....

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your schema?

Comment: Sure. I edited the original question to include it.

Comment: Are you using insecure package? If not, make sure you set up your collection permissions so that user profiles can be updated by authorized users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meteorpad indeed solved the issue. There was a mistake in the helper. In fact, the original code was:

```
Template.updateCustomerProfile.events({
getUsers: function () {
    return Meteor.user();
  }
});
```

So in above snippet I was using an 'events' instead of an 'helper'. Below is the correct code:

```
Template.updateCustomerProfile.helpers({
  getUsers: function(){
    return Meteor.user();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your [before AutoForm Hooks](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks).

```
AutoForm.addHooks(['profileForm'], {
  before: {
    insert: function(doc) {
      console.log('doc: ', doc);
      return doc;
    },

    update: function(doc) {
      console.log('doc: ', doc);
      return doc;
    },
  },
});
```

While the `after` callback has the js standard `(error, result)` function signature, the `before` callback has just one parameter, the doc to insert/update.  This is why you are always logging an 'error', it is just the doc you want to insert.  Also you need to either return it, or pass it to this.result to actually insert/update the object in the db.

[From the docs:](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks)

```
var hooksObject = {
  before: {
    // Replace `formType` with the form `type` attribute to which this hook applies
    formType: function(doc) {
      // Potentially alter the doc
      doc.foo = 'bar';

      // Then return it or pass it to this.result()
      return doc; (synchronous)
      //return false; (synchronous, cancel)
      //this.result(doc); (asynchronous)
      //this.result(false); (asynchronous, cancel)
    }
  },
```

Comment: I should indeed have seen that. Thanks for pointing out! However, even after changing to your suggestion, it does not work. I can insert new users into Mongo, but cannot seem to update existing users. In the Autohook I have a console.log that outputs the doc. I don't see errors, but somehow it seems as if the Mongo database is not updated. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really.  The best thing you can do would be to create a [mcve] as this question is far from that.  While doing so will create a question that more people will be able to assist on, it's value is also in the process, as by stripping it back you may find the solution yourself.  Create an example that doesn't use autoform hooks, doesn't require a flow:router, alanning:roles, etc.  There was a lot to stumble through just to find the above problem, and something I've mocked out may be masking another issue you have.  Anyway I'll try and get what I have working in meteorpad and post a link.

Comment: I saw one other error from flow:router not liking Meteor.userId() in the route subscriptions block, as the router is not reactive.  However I believe this is fairly harmless, as it will still use the current value when it executes - but will not respond if the value changes.

Comment: Here's the [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/r32LPrQzsDw8YZ8cq/ProfileAutoform)

Comment: I tried what you've put on meteorpad, and it seems to work doesnt it ?

Comment: That's what I thought! ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple small issues so I'm not sure how to tackle your problem, but here's some things to address.

**Publish Method**

- Local variable `user` is never used. Were you trying to use
  it?
- No need to include `userId` as a function parameter since you have
  access to `this.userId`
- The current user's profile is published by default so you don't need to use publish/subscribe unless you want to include/exclude fields, but then I would define a `Meteor.publish(null, ...)` so that it overrides the default current user publication

*Note: If you remove publish `usersAllforCustomer` function, don't forget to remove it from route `updateCustomerProfile`*

**Use Global Helper `currentUser`**

Here's how to update your template to use `currentUser` instead of `getUsers`

```
<template name="updateCustomerProfile">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit User</h1>
    {{#with currentUser}}
      {{#autoForm collection="Users" doc=this id="profileForm" type="update"}}
        <fieldset>
          {{> afQuickField name='username'}}
          {{> afObjectField name='profile'}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update User</button>
        <a class="btn btn-link" role="button" href="{{pathFor 'adminDocuments'}}">Back</a>
      {{/autoForm}}
    {{else}}
      Nothing
    {{/with}}
   </div>
</template>
```

Hope this helps.